# Does the address & operator return a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

The IMB documentation says : "The & (address) operator yields a pointer to its operand. The operand must be an lvalue, a function designator, or a qualified name. It cannot be a bit field".

Microsoft says : "The unary address-of operator (&) returns the address of (that is, a pointer to) its operand. The operand of the address-of operator can be a function designator or an lvalue that refers to an object that's not a bit field."

A lot of books say :"The address operator returns the address of the object".

Consider the following :

```
int x = 10;
&x;
*(&x) = 20;
```

1)Is &x simply an int* pointer ?

2)Does &x also encapsulates the information that it is referring to an int ? I guess so because if I compile the code and examine the assembly code I see :

- movl    $10, -4(%rbp)
- movl    $20, -4(%rbp)

Here movl is clearing moving 4 Bytes, so an int

3)Since different sources say that &a is an address and other say that it is a pointer does this bring to the final verdict that an address and a pointer are indeed the same ?

Comment: From Dennis Ritchie manual : "The unary &operator takes the address of its operand. The operand must be an Ivalue referring neither to a bit-field nor to an object declared as r e g i s t e r , or must be of function type. The result is a pointer to the object or function referred to by the Ivalue. If the type of the operand is T, the type of the result is "pointer to T." This is for all the people that keep saying that &x is not a pointer

Comment: The question of whether an address and a pointer are the same thing is pretty opinion-based.  This is a site for objective questions about software development, so you should try to frame your questions in terms of the behavior of programs, the behavior of compilers, or the C standard.

Comment: David Grayson, this is absolutely a question about software development because if you don't know pointers in C you don't know anything about it. As to the fact that it is pretty opinion-based it is NOT. The C bible from the creator of C actually says that &x IS A POINTER OF TYPE INT*. No further "opinions". Please consult the APPENDIX A at the point A7.4.2 of the "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. Software is not philosophy it is science, it is either 0 or 1. No opinions

Comment: "it is either 0 or 1." --> reminds me of "There are 3 types of people: Those who divided things in 2 groups and those who do not."

Comment: alessio, you're just arguing with me and talking about pointers, but you're not discussing addresses and you're failing to clarify what question you are asking in point 3.  If someone takes the time to write up an answer to #3, what criteria will you use to judge it?  Remember that "address" is very general term in English.  Instead of asking philosophy questions about whether "A and B are indeed the same", try to ask something objective.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the address & operator return a pointer in C?

Yes.

> Since different sources say that &a is an address and other say that it is a pointer does this bring to the final verdict that an address and a pointer are indeed the same ?

"Different sources" are not relevant unless one wants to consider that various sources may use the same word in different ways.  If that's your line of thinking, then the question is meaningless.  Otherwise, one source trumps all the others: the C language specification.  It says,

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type "*type*", the result has type "pointer to *type*".

(C23 6.5.3.2/3)

It is perhaps more precise, then, to say that the result of the operation of the unary `&` operator *has a pointer type*.  Inasmuch as this is among the very few ways that a C program can obtain an "address" as data, it is reasonable to understand it as **defining** pointer values as values representing addresses.<sup>*</sup>  (The other ways are array decay, function decay, and dynamic memory allocation, all of which are like `&` in yielding an address in the form of a pointer.)

> Is `&x` simply an `int*` pointer ?

Given `x` being an lvalue of type `int`, yes, `&x` has type `int *` (see above).

> Does `&x` also encapsulates the information that it is referring to an `int` ?

Sort of.  It is the data type of `&x`, `int *`, that captures the referenced type.  This is part of the semantics of the language, and of the unary `&` operator in particular.  However, it is not (generally speaking) encoded into the *value* of `&x`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Note, however, that saying "pointer values represent addresses" is not quite the same thing as saying "pointers *are* addresses" or *vice versa*.

Answer (score 0):

**1 and 2:** Yes, you can write `char * foo = &x;` and the compiler will complain to you because `char *` and `int *` are different, revealing that the compiler knows `&x` is an `int *` (pointer to an `int`).

**3:** That is an opinion-based question that depends on what you mean and who you ask.  Usually a compiler will implement a pointer as an address stored in some kind of memory, but sometimes it is smart enough that it doesn't need an address and can just directly access the object when you use the pointer.  And in that case, the object might not even have an address (e.g. if it's stored in a single CPU register).

Answer (score -1):

> #3 ... an address and a pointer are indeed the same ... ?

*address* / *pointer* /`int *` is like
*value* / *integer* /`int`:

generic/implementation/type.